# Android View Page indicator not changing color on page swipe

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am implementing the following listener to change pageindicator

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                try {
                    splash_text.setText(sliderText.get(arg0));
                    mIndicator.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listyou));
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                break;
            case 1:
                try {
                    splash_text.setText(sliderText.get(arg0));
                    mIndicator.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listyou));
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                break;
            case 2:
                try {
                    splash_text.setText(sliderText.get(arg0));
                    mIndicator.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listyou));
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                break;
            case 3:
                try {
                    splash_text.setText(sliderText.get(arg0));
                    mIndicator.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listyou));
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                break;
            case 4:
                try {
                    splash_text.setText(sliderText.get(arg0));
                    mIndicator.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listyou));
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

how to change the page indiactor color on page swipe. when i am doing
    mIndicator.setFillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listyou)) its not working.

Comment: What is `mIndicator`?

Comment: I am using a library http://viewpagerindicator.com/ from this site and its a CirclePageIndicator Class.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting color like.

```
mIndicator.setFillColor(Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.listyou)));
```